# About the lookat() function

Tags: webgl, glulookat

This is the function:

```
lookat(vec3 eye, vec3 at, vec3 up)
```

As we all know, the up vector can be`(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)`. It cannot be parallel to the observation vector `n`, or there will be somethingw wrong.

My question is how to calculate the up vector so that it passes through the point `eye` and is perpendicular to the `n` vector.

Comment: Read about the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: The Cross Product needs two vectors to get a result, but I only have one vector `n`.

Comment: If you only have 1 vector there are infinite solutions.